# How to prove that the set of positive integers is not complete under this metric?

Tags: metric-spaces

If we define a metric $d : \mathbb{Z^+} \times \mathbb{Z^+} \to \mathbb{R}$, where $\mathbb{Z^+}$ is the set of positive integers and $\mathbb{R}$ is the set of reals, as follows:

$$d(m,n) := |m^{-1}  - n^{-1}|$$

for all $m$, $n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$, then how to prove if this metric space is complete?

Comment: I think you mean $d \colon \mathbf{Z^+}\times \mathbf{Z^+} \to \mathbf{R^+}$.  As with your other question, a metric takes pairs of points in a space to a distance.

Comment: Oops sorry! It's the set of positive integers.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What's the limit of $a_n = n$? Is it a positive integer?